# Divide process workflow between remote workers

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, spring-batch, gigaspaces

I need to develop a Java platform to download and process information from Twitter. The basic idea is to have a centralized controller to generate tasks (id and keywords basically) and send this tasks to remote workers (one per computer). I need to receive an status report periodically to know about the status of both, the task and the worker. I'll have at least 60 workers (ten times more in a near future).

My initial idea was to use RMI but I need to communicate in both directions and I don't feel comfortable with RMI. The other approach was to use SSLSockets to send serialized objects but I would have to control a lot of errors and add a lot of code to monitor tasks and workers. Some people told me about use a framework like [Spring Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/), [Gigaspaces](http://www.gigaspaces.com) or [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org).

What do you think would be the best option for this project? By the time being I've read a lot of good things about Gigaspaces but I don't find a good tutorial about how to implement it and Quartz seems promising. What do you think? Is it worth using any of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not easy to tell you to go for a technology based on your question. GigaSpaces is certainly up to the job but so is Spring Batch. Quartz is just the scheduling part of your question and not so much the remoting and the distribution of workload.

GigaSpaces is a fully fledged application platform to handle scenario's where parallelism, high throughput and scalability is a factor. Spring Batch can definitely also do the job, but unlike GigaSpaces, it is not an application platform. So you would still need to deploy your application somewhere.

However, GigaSpaces is a commericial product (free version available) but there are other frameworks that can help you such as Storm Project (http://storm-project.net/) and Hazelcast (www.hazelcast.com) also come to mind.

So without clarifying your use case it's hard to give a single answer. It all depends on what exactly you want and how you want to use it, now and in the future.